# Defective washers in a sample of 20

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The diameter of washers produced by a machine has a mean of 0.502mm and a standard deviation of 0.005mm. Suppose that the maximum tolerance allows for diameters between 0.496mm and 0.508mm inclusive, otherwise a washer is classified as defective. Determine the percentage of defective washers produced by the machine, assuming that the diameters are normally distributed, and hence state how many defective washers you expect to see in a sample of 20 washers produced by this machine.

0,496 < x < 0,502

P[0,496- 0,502 /0,005 < x-m/sigma < 0,508 - 0,502 / 0,005]

P[-1.2 < z < 1.2]

1.2 = 0,3849

2x 0,3849 = 0,7698= 76,98%

100- 76,98= 23,02%

20 x 23,02 /100= 4,604 defective washers in my sample of 20

Is my reasoning correct?

`

Comment: Looks good at the first sight, but you should formulate the meaning of "$1.2=0.3849$" because just writing down such an equation could cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment:

Your first line says $0.496 < x < 0.502,$ but you intended and used
$0.496 < x < 0.508.$ And @Collodial_Machine (+1) and @Peter have already corrected some notation.

In R statistical software, with no intermediate rounding, this is closer to 4.603 expected defectives than to 4.604, but I'm not
sure that matters:

```
20*(1-diff(pnorm(c(.496,.508), .502, .005)))
## 4.60278
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it looks all right to me! Assuming that you meant

$P(z > 1.2) = 0.3849$ when you wrote  $1.2 = 0.3849$

Comment: Yes, I apologise for my notations. Thanks guys, really appreciated